# What is the source of the alien negative mental effects?

Tags: rimworld

When an alien ship crashes, you are suggested to deal with it quickly, and after a while negative things start happening to your colony (colonists and animals start going berserk, etc).

When you attack the ship, enemies come out. Do the negative events stop when you destroy the enemy units, when you destroy the ship itself, or after you destroy both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you destroy the ship itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the creator of the game himself, Tynan Sylvester, mentioning that the source of the negative effects is the crashed 'ship':